# I want to write to two different columns off of one line in an if else loop

Tags: r

I am trying to use a for if else loop to iterate through my data. For one of the loops I want to change two different columns, one with a formula and one with a written explanation of why the number is what it is. A snippet of my code follows.

```
library(MASS)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

if(((SGR >= 5 ) & (SGR30 <= 0 | is.na(SGR30)) & (SGR20 <= 0 | is.na(SGR20)) & (SGR10 <= 0 | is.na(SGR10)))) 
    {
    (DataWSGR[k,24] <- ((2/10*FactoredAADT*1) + FactoredAADT)) & (DataWSGR[k,25] <- "1%")
    }
```

When I run my code I get an error message that says

```
Error in (DataWSGR[k, 24] <- ((2/10 * FactoredAADT * 1) + FactoredAADT)) &  :
 operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.
```

What am I doing wrong to get both columns to change?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!!! Next time please provide a reproducible example. The reason why you get that error is because the `&` operator is a logical operator only used in logical tests and comparisons not in assignments.

For what you want, you have to put the assignments in two separate lines like so:

```r
library(MASS)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

if(((SGR >= 5 ) & (SGR30 <= 0 | is.na(SGR30)) & (SGR20 <= 0 | is.na(SGR20)) & (SGR10 <= 0 | is.na(SGR10)))) 
    {
    (DataWSGR[k,24] <- (2/10*FactoredAADT*1) + FactoredAADT) 
     DataWSGR[k,25] <- "1%"
    }
```